# Parsing twitter search string data to JSONArray in Android

Tags: android, json, twitter

Hi this is my first post on here. I am creating an app to search and get #tag tweets on my activity. 
I can get the tweets successfully from a user "1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name"
but when i get the data from "/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=", it is not passed to JSONArray and i get an exception. I believe it is in slightly different format.

How do i parse it properly to JSONArray?

Is there any alternative?

The data that i am getting back using "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=" gives me a JSON data int the following format

[{"created_at":"Fri Mar 21 01:07:41 +0000 2014","id":446815376790130689,"id_str":"446815376790130689","text":"@konishihiroyuki \u3069\u3046\u8aad\u3093\u3067\u3082\u3042\u306a\u305f\u306e\u307b\u3046\u304c\u304a....

Json Data from "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=" is in the following format

{"statuses":[{"metadata":{"result_type":"recent","iso_language_code":"de"},
"created_at":"Fri Jul 25 16:24:06 +0000 2014","id":492706869530488834,"id_str":"492706869530488834","text":"Bhagwant Mann EXPOSES Kabaddi Player Scam http://t.co/huGzZRvW59","source":"\u003ca href=\"http://www.facebook.com/twitter\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eFacebook\u003c/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":235322641,"id_str":"235322641","name":".....

```
    protected ArrayList<Tweet> doInBackground(String... param) {

        String searchStr = param[0];
        ArrayList<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>();
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(URL_SEARCH + searchStr);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            // using the access token (JSON format)
            String jsonString = autenticarApp();
            JSONObject jsonAcesso = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            String tokenPortador = jsonAcesso.getString("token_type") + " "
                    + jsonAcesso.getString("access_token");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", tokenPortador);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "application/json");
            connection.connect();

            // retrieving tweets from api
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    connection.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            StringBuilder strData = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                strData.append(line);
            }

            Log.d("GET response code", String.valueOf(connection.getResponseCode()));
            Log.d("JSON response", strData.toString());


            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(strData.toString());
            //debugger stops here and goes directly to exception                
            JSONObject jsonObject;

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                Tweet tweet = new Tweet();

                tweet.setName(jsonObject.getJSONObject("user").getString("name"));
                //tweet.setUser(jsonObject.getJSONObject("user").getString("screen_name"));
                //tweet.setUrlProfileImage(jsonObject.getJSONObject("user").getString("profile_image_url"));
                //tweet.setMessage(jsonObject.getString("text"));
                //tweet.setDate(jsonObject.getString("created_at"));
                tweets.add(i, tweet);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error GET: ", Log.getStackTraceString(e));

        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return tweets;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the string you obtain is not rappresenting an array, but an object ("statuses")
so you have first to create a json object with it, then a json array...
something like that

```
JSONObject jobjArray = new JSONObject(strData.toString());

JSONArray jarrTweets = (JSONArray)jobjArray.get("statuses");

JSONObject joTweet;

for (int i = 0; i < jarrTweets.length(); i++) 
{
         joTweet = (JSONObject) jarrTweets.get(i);
         Tweet tweet = new Tweet();

         tweet.setName(joTweet.getJSONObject("user").getString("name"));

         ...
```